# Codeigniter Cookies Help

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

Hello in codeigniter how would I check if the user is visiting the site for the first time, and if they are set a cookie?

I am already using the Session library and database sessions which stores the session_id etc, but I need to to be able to check if the user is a first time visitor and if they have a cookie already
`

```
$cookie = array(
                           'name'   => 'some_value',
                           'value'  => 'The Value',
                           'expire' => time()+86500,
                           'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
                           'path'   => '/',
                           'prefix' => '',
                       );

        set_cookie($cookie);
        var_dump(get_cookie('some_value'));`
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the KohanaPHP framework? http://kohanaphp.com it's a branch of the CodeIgniter framework and is more innovative IMHO; years ago I used to use CodeIgniter but joined the group of users that got sick of the slow and unresponsive development of CodeIgniter by Rick Ellis and co.

Comment: @Ixmatus - Switching frameworks just so you could set a cookie is pure madness.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the cookie helper, you could check if a user is a first time visitor by doing:

```
if (!get_cookie('some_value')) {
    // cookie not set, first visit

    // create cookie to avoid hitting this case again
    $cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'some_value',
        'value'  => 'The Value',
        'expire' => time()+86500,
        'domain' => '.some-domain.com',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => '',
    );
    set_cookie($cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Cookie Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html) to get/set cookies.

Comment: I am using the cookie helper, please see my amended post for the code I am using

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else finding odd results when using codeignighters cookies be sure that the cookie was set using codeignighters $this->input->set_cookie instead of PHP's own setcookie method.

I had strange results until I clear all cookies and reset it with codeignighters own method.

Answer (score 0):

fist of all you need to know the basic Idea about cookie
**Session** is creating in server where as a **cookie** is creating in the clients browser.

so the cookie get created when ever you browse the php file (In which the set cookie code is ter)

And from the next request onward you will get the section to read